# When does wxpython event object get declared within the Bind and event handling logic?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have working wxpython code, but I don't understand some logic.  In the code, a scroll event is assigned to an 'OnSliderScroll' event handler.

```
sld.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)
```

OnSliderScroll is defined as such:

```
def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
  obj = e.GetEventObject()
  ...
```

But "e" isn't declared anywhere (at least it isn't done explicitly).  I expected something like

```
e = ...
```

Where/when does "e" get declared?

Comment: why do you need to declare it? it is a formal parqmeter name and can be anything you want.

Comment: As an aside, this sort of confusion often arises due to a habit as old as programming, the desire to type as little as possible. It's regularly coded as `e` or slightly better `evt`. If you always code it as `event`, you know instantly what it is. That goes for every other variable as well. Using meaningful names, avoids confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`e` is the object representing the event itself and passed, by convention, to all event handlers. It's defined inside wxPython itself, which is why you don't see it in your own code, but it's declared in your event handler definition -- as its parameter.

Comment: do you know where in the wxPython documentation what you said is specified?  I don't remember that explanation when I sifted through the online docs.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know much about wxPython docs. wxWidgets own [event handling overview](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.2/overview_events.html) might be helpful, although you will have to ignore all the C++-specific parts, of course.